# PHP arrays and html forms

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a script that will take a random variable from a list of chars. I have `+ &` before of each letter. This is what I have come up with so far

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $str = $_POST["text"];

    $arr1 = str_split($str);



   foreach ($arr1 as $value)
   {
     $length = 1; 
     $chars = '46eab95'; 
     $charslength = strlen($chars); 
     $randomstring = ''; 
     for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) $randomstring .= substr($chars, rand(0, $charslength - 1), 1); 
       echo $randomstring;  
       echo "&" . $randomstring . $value;
     }
   }
?>
```

But it just is screwed up and won't work, For instance when I try to make it do Hello this is what comes out:  `6&6h4&4e4&4l6&6l5&5o`

Comment: Can you give us an example of your expected output?

Comment: Remove the `#` in your action, not sure your form is posted.

Comment: You should also think about the fact that you do echo twice in the same loop, might be what bugs it aswell.

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to do this, and what it should look like?

Answer (score 1):

A little rewritten - does this work for you?

```
<?php
$str = "hello";
$arr1 = str_split($str);

foreach ($arr1 as $value)
{
    $chars = '46eab95'; 
    $chars = str_split($chars);

    $randomstring = ''; 
    foreach ($arr1 as $char)
    {
        $randomstring .= "&" . $chars[array_rand($chars)] . $char;
    }
}

echo $randomstring; //&bh&ee&4l&9l&eo
```

Comment: its giving &0's as a option but its not listed in the chars

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Have updated the code. `array_rand` does not return the element from the array as I thought, but the key.